# What object collection should I have to add objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, prism, observablecollection

I'm using Prism in WPF.

I was watching the Prism starter kit, and it has a ICollectionView. In that collection, I need to add the object selected in it. What object (or collection) should I use to add objects?

[image]

I mean in the image, I have two listbox, in the first one I've got a readonly collection and the second one is a list where can add or remove objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your List should be bound to an ICollectionView that wraps an ObservableCollection. When you add, you add to this Observable collection.

I.e

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Stock> listToAddTo;

public ICollectionView List2 { get; private set; }
```

Constructor

```
  listToAddTo = new ObservableCollection<Stock>();
  List2 = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listToAddTo);
```

Where List2 is what is bound to